# How to authenticate DRV Via FFMPEG

Tags: iphone, authentication, ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg i was able to get stream from a cam, channel and a recorded video but when i tries to access a protected DVR i always gets failed with error like

- connection refused
- 404 no page found
- cseq missing, 504 options are not implemented
  ...........

I tried with many different url options like

- rtsp://username:password@mysite.com
- rtsp://username:password@mysite.com:554
- rtsp://username:password@mysite.com:80
- http://username:password@mysite.com:80
- http://mysite.com?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD

but all in vein

Can anybody help me getting this done, alternatives to FFMEG are welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: i used ip address instead of any dns based website/server name i.e 216.113.94.103 instead of my site.com